# PHP table echoing 0 results

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a table to show users in my database and it's echoing 0 results for some reason. There are over 40,000 entries in my database so there is definitely something wrong with my PHP code but I'm just not sure where.

```
<?php 
require 'session.php';
require 'header.php'; 
include 'database.php';
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY time_edit DESC LIMIT 45";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>ID</th>";
    echo "<th>IP</th>";
    echo "<th>Connections</th>";
    echo "<th>Last Seen</th>";
    echo "<th>Rank</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$name=$row['name'];
$id=$row['id'];
$ip=$row['ip'];
$connections=$row['connections'];
$seen=$row['time_edit'];
$rank=$row['group_bits'];
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=center> $name </td>";
    echo "<td align=center> $id </td>";
    echo "<td align=center> $ip </td>";
    echo "<td align=center> $connections </td>";
    echo "<td align=center> $seen </td>";
    echo "<td align=center> $rank </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You're not doing any error checking on your queries. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: Silly me, the database file was located in includes/database.php .. Thank you! :)